# Detecting Mouse position in Firefox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect mouse position inside the element through on mouse move event but it does not work in Firefox.

```
function mouseover_imageChange(imgid,imgArr) {
    var x= event.pageX- jQuery("#"+imgid).offset().left;
    var y= event.pageY- jQuery("#"+imgid).offset().top;
}
```

Any idea on how to make it work in all browsers, along with the parameters that are needed to be passed to the function?

Thanks,
Muhtu

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It is probably the global `window.event` object in IE.

Comment: `mouseover` a is bad selection for this. Try `mousemove`

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using jQuery, why not use something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var startImgTracker = function (e) {
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify({
                "x": e.pageX,
                "y": e.pageY,
                "relativeX": e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                "relativeY": e.pageY - $(this).offset().top
            }));
        });
    };
    var stopImgTracker = function (e) {
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');
    };
    $('img').hover(startImgTracker, stopImgTracker);
});
```

Use the `hover` event to trigger a `mousemove` handler (which is what you appear to want) and the "stop"`hover` event to unbind the `mousemove`. Make sure to include an event argument to get the current `pageX` and `pageY`.

This should work in any browser that will run jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

@Muthu

Here is a working demo of "getting X and Y coordinates of the mouse in the viewport" http://jsfiddle.net/XsqBz/

And please find below the complete source. Enjoy.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<title>jQuery: Getting X and Y coordinates of the mouse in the viewport</title> 
<style> 
html{background:#f9f9f9;background-color:#f9f9f9;} 

body{background:#fff;background-color:#fff;color:#666;font-family:"Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Georgia,"Bitstream Vera Sans","Bitstream Charter",sans-serif,serif;margin:2em auto;width:700px;padding:1em 2em;-moz-border-radius:11px;-khtml-border-radius:11px;-webkit-border-radius:11px;border-radius:11px;border:1px solid #dfdfdf;} 

body{ 
font-size:11px; 
line-height:15px; 
background:#fff;
background-color:#fff; 
color:#666; 
margin-left:20px; 
} 

strong{font-size:12px;}
a:link{color:#0066CC;}
a:hover{color:#FF6600;}
a:visited{color:#003366;}
a:active{color:#9DCC00;} 

p{font-size:18px;} 

.relativeX, .relativeY{color:#666;font-size:13pt;} 
.relativeX{font-size:48pt;color:#fc0;position:relative;top:-20px;left:30px;} 
.relativeY{font-size:52pt;position:relative;top:-09px;left:-10px;} 
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<!-- Move mouse over div to get position --> 
<div style="margin:10px;height:400px;width:90%;min-width:420px;background:#ccc;padding:20px;border:1px dotted #777;display:block;"> 
  relative to this 
</div>  
<script> 
(function($) { 
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function(){ 
  return false; 
}); 

  $('div').mousemove(function(e){ 
    // Relative to this div element instead of document 
    var relativeX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; 
    var relativeY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $(this).html('releativeX = <span class="relativeX">' + relativeX + '</span>, releativeY = <span class="relativeY">' + relativeY + '</span>'); 
  }); 
})(jQuery); 
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```